# Several foreach loop in one blade

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have four blades with CRUD, for each table in DB.

In homeblade I need table where I can put one column from each table, and fill it in column, not in a row.

This is my code in blade:

```
<div class="container">
        <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Companies</th>
                    <th>Devices</th>
                    <th>Vehicles</th>
                    <th>Drivers</th>
                </tr>

                     @foreach($companies as $company)
                    <tr>
                    <td>{{$company->name}}</td>
                    @endforeach

                    @foreach($devices as $device)
                    <td>{{$device->type}}</td>
                    @endforeach

                    @foreach($vehicles as $vehicle)
                    <td>{{$vehicle->license_plate}}</td>
                    @endforeach

                    @foreach($drivers as $driver)
                    <td>{{$driver->name}}</td>
                    @endforeach
                    </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

And I need table to look this way
[Picture of table that I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjJcW.png)

I tried few diferent variations for foreach loop and for tables, but I have no more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one `foreach`

```
@foreach($companies as $key => $company)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$company->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$devices[$key]->type}}</td>
        <td>{{$vehicles[$key]->license_plate}}</td>
        <td>{{$drivers[$key]->name}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: May be a `!empty()` or `isset()` check.

Comment: I got eror: Undefined ofset

Answer (score 0):

It only can be done with making array in new controller.

```
class WelcomeController extends Controller {
public function index(Request $request) {

    $items = [];
    foreach (Companies::all() as $comp) $items[]['company']=$comp;
    foreach (Device::all() as $index => $dev){
        if($items[$index]) $items[$index]['device']=$dev;
        else $items[]['device']=$dev;
    }

    foreach (Vehicle::all() as $index => $veh){
        if($items[$index]) $items[$index]['vehicle']=$veh;
        else $items[]['vehicle']=$veh;
    }

    foreach (Driver::all() as $index => $dr){
        if($items[$index]) $items[$index]['driver']=$dr;
        else $items[]['driver']=$dr;
    }



    return view('/welcome', ['items'=>$items]);
}
```

And in body of table in blade I wrote this:

```
<tbody>

                @foreach($items as $company)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{isset($company['company'])?$company['company']->name:''}}</td>
                    <td>{{isset($company['device'])?$company['device']->type:''}}</td>
                    <td>{{isset($company['vehicle'])?$company['vehicle']->type:''}}</td>
                    <td>{{isset($company['driver'])?$company['driver']->name:''}}</td>

                </tr>
                @endforeach

            </tbody>
```